# angularjs ajax loading directive

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs

I am trying to build a directive that will show a loading graphic when doing ajax requests on a page.
I have set this up:

```
.directive('ajaxLoader', ['$http', function ($http) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attr) {
            scope.isLoading = function () {
                return $http.pendingRequests.length > 0;
            };

            scope.$watch(scope.isLoading, function (loading) {
                if (!loading) {
                    element.addClass('ng-hide');
                }
            });
        }
    }
}]);
```

which works fine if there is only one ajax directive on a page.
The Html I currently have is like this:

```
<div class="fixed animated fadeIn">
    <nav class="top-bar" role="navigation">
        <!-- cut for brevity -->

        <section ng-controller="ProfileController as controller">
            <div class="loading" ajax-loader></div>
            <ul ng-show="controller.user">
                <li>
                    <a href="#/security/login">
                        <h1>
                            <span class="right profile-image">

                            </span>
                            <span ng-bind="controller.user.firstName"></span><br />
                            <span class="small" ng-bind="controller.user.lastName"></span>
                        </h1>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </section>
    </nav>
</div>

<div class="row" ng-controller="CustomerServicesController as controller">
    <!-- cut for brevity  -->

    <section class="col-md-3">
        <h2>Recent orders</h2>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="medium-12 columns data">
                <div class="loading" ajax-loader></div>

                <table ng-hide="controller.recent.length === 0">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Account</th>
                        <th>Raised by</th>
                        <th>Reference</th>
                        <th>Detail</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr ng-repeat="order in controller.recent" id="{{order.orderNumber}}">
                        <td><strong ng-bind="order.account.accountNumber"></strong> <span ng-bind="order.account.name"></span></td>
                        <td ng-bind="order.raisedBy"></td>
                        <td ng-bind="order.orderNumber"></td>
                        <td ng-bind="order.description"></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
```

Now, what appears to happen is that both loaders stay up for the same amount of time (it's like they are waiting for the other to finish before they disappear). If I refresh the screen I see both loading graphics appear and then when both areas have finished their calls, both images disappear. I would like them to work independently, does anyone know how I can do this?

Also, on another smaller issue, the data seems to be loaded a split second before the images disappear. Is there a way to get them to show/hide at the same time? Or if not possible, get the loader to disappear before the data is loaded in the DOM?

Comment: Will obviously need to bind them to something else since you have no way to distinguish use case of `pendingRequests`. Lots of other ways you could approach this

Comment: https://github.com/yangular/angular-pageblock

Comment: @YangLi that is almost the same as I am using. But instead of blocking the entire screen, I want to just show a spinner for the bit that is doing the request. So if there are 4 ajax requests on a page, then there are 4 spinners each tied to the particular request.